# /etc files on a different partition

Tags: partition, symlink, group

My setup requires that some of my `/etc` files reside on a separate partition. For this purpose I've created a softlink:

```
ls -li /etc/group
956 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May  7 15:48 /etc/group -> /var/common/etc/group

ls -li /var/common/etc/group
3145744 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 668 May 11 11:02 /var/common/etc/group
```

My problem is when I try to execute commands using these files:

```
groupadd foo
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
```

`strace` reports:

```
rename("/etc/group+", "/var/common/etc/group") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
write(2, "groupadd: failure while writing "..., 54groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
) = 54
```

Any ideas how I can get `groupadd` to work?

Comment: Why that files are on the other partitions? you yourself did it? or it was installed so? On Which distro?

Comment: CentOS. The system has to be partitioned this way (by me) for various unrelated reasons.

Comment: Are you executing the commands using sudo or as root?

Comment: Also, I did not think you could make symlinks across partitions.

Comment: @ChrisR. Commands are executed as root. Symlinks are allowed across partitions. I can successfully edit the /etc/group file by hand without problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant hardlinks, but it is late.  The error you are getting is acting like it is a hard link.  Have you tried recreating the symlink?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Splitting files in `/etc` across partitions is a bad idea for this reason.

What is happening is that the `groupadd` utility is creating a temporary file, and then replacing the real `/etc/groups` file (or rather, what the symlink points to) with the temporary one via a simple `rename` operation.
The catch is that `rename()` only works on the same filesystem, otherwise it throws an error.

Another potential issue you can run into here is that when something goes to do the `rename`, it clobbers the symlink, and now it's an ordinary file.

Another potential issue is that many files in `/etc` are required for proper boot, before the system has a chance to mount other volumes. Thus those files will in effect be missing.

In short, no, this can't be fixed. And it shouldn't be done anyway.

Comment: I completely disagree. This *should* be done - `/etc` should be kept in `initramfs` if done properly.

Comment: @mikeserv If /etc/ is placed on initramfs, how do you successfully use commands like groupadd, useradd...?

Comment: @mikeserv that would be a different setup. The problem here and what Patrick is referring to, is that `/etc` should not be split across multiple partitions. Not that `/etc` _needs_ to be on the `/` partitions, only that everything _under_ `/etc` be on the same partition.

Comment: @Chaimkut You don't need to be rid of *initramfs* after boot, you know.

Comment: @terdon actually it does need to be on the `/` partition. For example, `/etc/fstab` is needed to mount the other partitions (unless doing some initramfs magic).

Comment: @mikeserv Why would `/etc` be in initramfs? Every single time you reboot, any changes you've made to `/etc` will be gone.

Comment: Ah, even more so then. Thanks. My point was that, based on what I understood from your answer, `/etc` can't be split across multiple partitions because of the `rename` calls you explained. Whether it needs to be on `/` or not is yet another issue correct?

Comment: Different issue yes. An aspect I did not cover, so you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc` is meant to be on the root filesystem. The sane thing to do is to keep it that way.

If you really really need to split `/etc`, you might get better results with a union mount. I don't know if Linux supports union mounts where one of the components matches the mount point, though, and it would be difficult to not make the real `/etc` on the root filesystem part of the union mount.

If you want to put all of `/etc` on a different partition, you can make a minimal `/etc` that contains just what is needed (`/etc/fstab`, what init needs (`/etc/inittab` or `/etc/init` and `/etc/rc*` or whatever your init system uses), minimal `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, etc.). Early during boot (a lot earlier than `/etc/rc.local`!), bind-mount `/var/common/etc` onto `/etc`. But that's going to require a lot of work to get right, and it'll result in `/var/common/etc` being the whole `/etc`, which is probably not what you want. This setup mostly makes sense for some embedded systems that don't use any of the usual init systems and have a stringent contraint on the size of the root filesystem.

If you have a `/var/common` that is shared between many servers, you should approach the problem differently. Use a proper configuration management system to deploy shared files to `/etc`.

A file like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` should not be shared between machines. Use these files only for local users and groups. For entries that are shared across machines, use NIS or LDAP.